# Report progress in client/server environment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a strange problem when reporting progress of the long running server operation.
The application has client/server architecture and written in C#. Client uses WPF.

On client side I create progress window and start in background worker a long running operation. This operation is a server method called via remoting. As argument server method accepts special ProgressContext object that is used to report progress (see code below).

As soon as server starts performing some heavy operations that utilize CPU/Memory - the progress window becomes frozen. Its not responding to any interactions and do not update progress. After a while when heavy operations are done - the progress window comes back to live like nothing happened.

It looks like when I pass instance of background worker to the server and server thread is heavy loaded - it some how locks the window backgroundworker is related to. If I use the same progress window without remoting calls - problem dissapears.

To report progress I use progress window with backgroundworker as in many samples around the web.
here is C# code for the progress window:

```
public partial class ProgressWindow : Window
{
    #region Fields

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoIncrementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AutoIncrement",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ProgressBar),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private readonly BackgroundWorker m_worker;
    private CultureInfo m_culture;
    private bool m_isCancelled;
    private Exception m_error = null;

    private Action<IProgressContext> m_workerCallback;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Inits the dialog without displaying it.
    /// </summary>
    public ProgressWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //init background worker
        m_worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        m_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        m_worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        m_worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
        m_worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        AutoIncrement = true;
        CancellingEnabled = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public bool CancellingEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return btnCancel.IsVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            btnCancel.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public bool Cancelled
    {
        get
        {
            return m_isCancelled;
        }
    }

    public bool AutoIncrement
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(AutoIncrementProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(AutoIncrementProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Exception Error
    {
        get
        {
            return m_error;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Run(Action<IProgressContext> action)
    {
        if (AutoIncrement)
        {
            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        }

        //store the UI culture
        m_culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

        //store reference to callback handler and launch worker thread
        m_workerCallback = action;
        m_worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        //display modal dialog (blocks caller)
        ShowDialog();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    #region Event Handlers

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //make sure the UI culture is properly set on the worker thread
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = m_culture;

            ProgressContext context = new ProgressContext((BackgroundWorker)sender);

            //invoke the callback method with the designated argument
            m_workerCallback(context);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //disable cancelling and rethrow the exception
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                   (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { btnCancel.SetValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty, false); },
                                   null);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnCancel.IsEnabled = false;
        m_worker.CancelAsync();
        m_isCancelled = true;
    }

    private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage != int.MinValue)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        if (e.UserState != null)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = (string)e.UserState;
        }
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            m_error = e.Error;
        }

        //update UI in case closing the dialog takes a moment
        btnCancel.IsEnabled = false;

        Close();
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}

public class ProgressContext : MarshalByRefObject, IProgressContext
{
    #region Fields

    private BackgroundWorker m_worker;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ProgressContext(BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        m_worker = worker;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public void ReportProgress(string message)
    {
        m_worker.ReportProgress(int.MinValue, message);
    }

    public void ReportProgress(int progress, string message)
    {
        m_worker.ReportProgress(progress, message);
    }

    public void ReportProgress(int progress)
    {
        m_worker.ReportProgress(progress);
    }

    public bool IsCancelled
    {
        get
        {
            return m_worker.CancellationPending;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would need more details (and probably code) on remoting used here.

Comment: Try to set the `progressBar` value using the `Dispatcher` class and `DispatcherPriority.Background`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant provide detailed code of the server side operations performed as they take thousands of lines. Remoting setup has nothing special and works well in all cases. The problem occurs not immediately. Progress is reported and then after a while when heavy operations come - UI is stuck. If there is something that cound cause this behaviour I would be glad to check. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried using Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke as well as setting up priorities. This does not help. Interesting thing is thet when using result Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (DispatcherOperation)to check state - is says Pending when the UI is frozen.

Comment: One more thing. It does not matter If I set the value of the progress bar or leave it to be IsIndeterminate - it does not matter. Its just enough to report progress by changing text of the label. The UI will got frozen after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input.

The reason for the problem was another process that in different thread was accessing server methods via its own Dispatcher.Invoke and causing locks. This process startups were rare - thus it made an impression of locking up after a while.

The overall recommendation I can give is to make Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke methods as light as possible without any heavy calculations inside. Do your server job beforehand and use them just to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Backgroundworker is not fit for being marshaled using remoting this way.

Leave the Backgroundworker at the client, do not pass it and setup an event sink that is a MarshalByRefObject which remains on the client and is called/signaled from the server.

The sink in its turn can invoke methods on the Backgroundworker.

Comment: Actually if I got you right this is exactly what I have right now - ProgressContext class is MarshalByRef. And it is the one that is passed through the remoting boundaries. When its method is called from server side - on client side it calls its m_worker corresponding methods (see code posted in original message). Or you ment something different?

Comment: Ah, yes now I understand your code. Did you mark the callback as OneWay?

Comment: The remoting part is not written in WCF. It is plain old remoting.

Comment: Look up: `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.OneWay` :)

Comment: Never used this attribute. Thanks for the info. Although this does not affect the problem.